# How to re-import products with existing images

Tags: product-images, image, importexport, magento-1.9.3.2

I have accidentally **deleted** all **product** from **Magento store** (1100 items) but few minutes before that I did export all of them to the .csv file what let me to import them back but unfortunately there no single image back.

Is there a way to assign all these images back? I assume images are still in media/product? I have access to MySQL but how to prepare SQL query to reassign those images? I don't have fresh enough backup and this is a live store so I'm quite desperate.

Thank you.

Comment: put all of your picture in media/import before import

Comment: path to the images in exported CSV file is /[first_letter]/[second_letter]/image_name.png but in /media/product/ images are stored in [xxx]/image_name.png so coping them all to /media/import/ will fail to reassing them.

Answer (score 0):

If the image columns are in your CSV. All you have to do is place the product images from media/catalog/product under media/import and re-import your CSV. It will then detect and assign them. Make sure that the paths in your CSV match what's below media/import. There's plenty of documentation on this.

- http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-import-product-images.html

Make sure to never mess with your production database ever again. If you're uncertain of what can go wrong, It's a small effort to make a backup of your MySQL database first. If you ever have to do something tricky with your production database again, make sure to have a running copy next to it. This way, if something goes wrong, you only have to swap the database name in your local.xml and clear your cache. Though working in production is not advised, if you have to do it, make sure you have a plan B.

Comment: I wasn't messing with database, I have just clicked [select all] thinking will select only visible ones instead of all in catalog before deleting.

Comment: path to the images in exported CSV file is /[first_letter]/[second_letter]/image_name.png but in /media/product/ images are stored in [xxx]/image_name.png so coping them all to /media/import/ will fail to reassing them.
P.S. I have managed to recover dump of database with just catalog_* tables.